# how to get index of array in javascript whihout knowing its value

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am creating an array of textboxes.   and each box has a corresponding del and edit option.

```
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    <input type='text' id='pp_insti' name='pp_insti[]' value='"+institute+"' style='display:none;'>
    <input type='button' class='edit-button' id='pp_edit name='pp_edit[]' onclick='pp_edit();'/>
<input type='button' class='del-button' id='pp_del name='pp_del[]' onclick='pp_del();'/>
    }
```

what value of index should i pass for pp_edit so i know which pp_inst[] to edit.

can anyone help.. thanks

Comment: your code seems invalid in javascript .

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create several textboxes with the same `ID` (`pp_insti`). This is not allowed.

Instead, you could give them IDs such as `pp_insti_1`, `pp_insti_2` etc, based on the value of `i`. You could then pass the value of `i` to the edit and delete functions as well, to be able to find the text box of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass a value, because the onclick handler is run with an event variable automatically passed to it. Therefore change your function definition of `pp_edit()` to `pp_edit(ev)`, and then inside the function use `elem=ev.target`, where elem will be the DOM element that was clicked on.

Alternatively, you could pass the `this` keyword to each call of pp_edit: `onclick='pp_edit(this);`, then define pp_edit: `pp_edit(obj)`. Now in pp_edit, `obj` refers to the clicked element.

The third alternative is to set the onclick handlers programatically, instead of in-line:

```
for(....){
  elem=document.createElement('...');
  elem.onclick=pp_edit;
}
```

Now, when pp_edit is called, it will be within the context of the clicked element, and inside pp_edit, the `this` keyword will refer to the clicked element.

NOTE: as another user pointed out, your code is invalid, but I am assuming you posted it that way to get your point across. If not, you definitely need to lookup functions like `document.createElement()`.